# How to remove extra character from http request?

Tags: .htaccess

I noticed some links to my site that have one extra character after the correct url, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/mainpage.html" instead of 
www.mysite.com/mainpage.html
```

I've been using some simple straight-forward code for each URI, such as

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/page1\.html\"$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/ page1.html [R=301,L]
```

But this of course is a dumb approach.

Is it possible to fix all such links with one RewriteRule? In other words, remove the extra character from any request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple rule to remove all extra text after `.html` from an URI:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?\.html).+$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `^(.+?\.html).?$`

Comment: `^(.+?\.html).?$` will cause infinite looping. We have to make sure that there is some text after `.html` by using `.+`

Comment: This would remove query parameters. How about `^(.+?\.html).{1}$`

Comment: Nope it won't remove any query string because `RewriteRule` doesn't match any query string. It can only match REQUEST_URI